# DialogFlow + LINE.me integration with rich messages

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, line.me

I am integrating DialogFlow and LINE using fulfillment webhook. I am able to successfully reply the message to user's LINE when the text is in the `speech` field of the response.

```
{
  "speech": "your number is 1234"
}
```

However, if I follow the document and add the LINE specific response, it does **not** work, meaning it simply replies nothing.

```
{
  "data": {
    "line": {
      "replyToken": "e4050bccd34b52...b119069d27bb5",
      "messages": [
        {
          "text": "Hi",
          "type": "text"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This means that I can only reply with a single text message, but not other rich messages.

Am I doing something wrong or it is DialogFlow's problem?

Comment: it can be possible that line does not support the rich messages like rich messages are not supported for web demo.

Comment: It has a set of rich messages defined: https://developers.line.me/en/docs/messaging-api/reference/#message-objects. At any rate, even if I tried using the 'text' type, it is still not working.

Comment: can you share your code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it!
The response format in the question is not correct. The correct format is something like:

```
{
 'messages': [
   <message object>,
   <message object>
 ]
}
```

You can refer to [message object](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/message-objects) for what types can be used.
One thing to note is with type 4, you can simply use the payload specified in [LINE](https://developers.line.me/en/docs/messaging-api/reference/#template-messages).

For example,

```
{
    'messages': [
        {
            'type': 0,
            'speech': 'ABC'
        },
        {
            "type": 4,
            "payload": {
                "line": {
                    "type": "template",                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "altText": "This is a buttons template",
                    "template": {
                        "type": "buttons",
                        "thumbnailImageUrl": "https://images.justlanded.com/event_images/Tets/photo/events_original_45195_42919.jpg",
                        "imageAspectRatio": "rectangle",
                        "imageSize": "cover",
                        "imageBackgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
                        "title": "Menu",
                        "text": "Please select",
                        "defaultAction": {
                            "type": "uri",
                            "label": "View detail",
                            "uri": "http://example.com/page/123"
                        },
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "postback",
                                "label": "Buy",
                                "data": "action=buy&itemid=123"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "postback",
                                "label": "Add to cart",
                                "data": "action=add&itemid=123"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "uri",
                                "label": "View detail",
                                "uri": "http://example.com/page/123"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    ]
}
```